# Linking a URL(Hyperlink) to a PHP method

Tags: php, html, url, href

I have several links on a page, all of which need to execute a different method in PHP.
A link for "Create File", one for "Rename File" and one for "Delete file".

The only way I know of to execute PHP code with each hyperlink is by giving the URL of a different PHP file to each  hyperlink.

Is there a way to link the URL (HREF) to a SPECIFIC method in a PHP file?
Here are a few lines of code that do not work, but might help you understand what I want to achieve:

```
<a href="fileManagement.php::createFile()">Create File</a>
<a href="fileManagement.php::renameFile()">Rename File</a>
<a href="fileManagement.php::deleteFile()">Rename File</a>
```

I'm also pretty sure I'm taking the wrong approach, but I'm too much of a PHP novice to know better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common approach in your situation would be setting a GET parameter called something like fileAction and then switching it's value, so your links would look like this:

```
<a href="fileManagement.php?fileAction=create">Create File</a>
<a href="fileManagement.php?fileAction=rename">Rename File</a>
<a href="fileManagement.php?fileAction=delete">Delete File</a>
```

And your filemanagement.php logiс would look somewhat like this:

```
<?php 
$fileAction = $_GET['fileAction'];
switch ($fileAction) {
    case 'create':
        createFile();
        break;
    case 'rename':
        renameFile();
        break;
    case 'delete':
        deleteFile();
        break;
    default:
        //your default logic here
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can send the method name as a $_GET value and execute the corresponding function, like so:

HTML:

```
 <a href="functions.php?method=someMethod">Run some method</a>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_GET['method'])) {
 $method = $_GET['method'];
 $method();
 }
```

Comment: ` $method = $_GET['method'];
 $method();` Wow. So there's no need for any if/switch case, but just passing it like that and calling $method() executes it?

Comment: Yes. it's that simple... Obviously you would want to do some validation to see that the method does exist.

Comment: By the way, if you are working on a big project, you might want to look into some more advanced solutions,  in the form of MVC frameworks, that inherently incorporate such abilities. I'd personally recommend Laravel or CodeIgniter

Comment: By the way, let's say the file contains 20+ methods... would I need 20 if statements/switch statements to validate the method given? Or can I catch the exception or something similar that will check if the method exists in the file?

Comment: Again, no need for switch statement. Use PHP's native `function_exists()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Comment: Good lords, people. Don't follow this approach! It's horribly insecure and allows any attacker to call any defined function. Use a white-list as in Konnigun's answer.

Comment: What if I use POST instead of GET?

Comment: @Tino, he can easily pass an array of allowed methods and check if it's in the array. That's included within validation. there is nothing inherently wrong with this approach, and it definitely doesn't justify a downvote. Also, avoiding unnecessary switch\if statements is more elegant.

Comment: @David, POST doesn't help. Matanya, it is inherently wrong. Even validating it against some array leaves it open to security holes with regards to \0 and PHP's often strange re-interpretation of values. The only correct way is a white-list where you explicitly call the function, like Konnigun showed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    @$Method = $_GET['Method'];
    if (!(isset($Method)))
    {
        $Method = "0"; // If URL does not contain ?Method=1 Then Assign It To 0 
    }
    if ($Method > "3")
    {
        $Method = "0";
        // If ?Method= value is higher than 3 Then Set it to 0 
    }
    if ($Method == "0")
    {
        echo "<a href=\"fileManagement.php?Method=1\">Create File</a>";
        echo "<a href=\"fileManagement.php?Method=2\">Rename File</a>";
        echo "<a href=\"fileManagement.php?Method=3\">Delete File</a>";
    }
    elseif ($Method == "1")
    {
        // Method = 1 Is Create File So:
        // CreateFile();
    }
    elseif ($Method == "2")
    {
        // Method 2 is Rename File 
        // renameFile();

    }
    elseif ($Method == "3")
    {
        // Method 3 Is Delete File
        // deleteFile();
    }


?>
```

Comment: Also, I think for something like this a switch case would do better :) Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: As $Method is already set, It's in best practice to unset (destroy) the current setting of $method before assigning it a new one.

Comment: That's fine, Just fixed the bugs present on the file,

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the perfect scenario for using an MVC framework. There are tons of these frameworks out there and they help you in organising your code better. If you are just starting out in PHP, I highly suggest you to look at a framework and some code samples on the web in order to get your head around the MVC principle.

When using an MVC framework, you simply define *routes* which map to a particular function (action) in a particular class (controller). I won't get too far in this answer, but I suggest you go through these ressources to get you started :

- [MVC definition on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
- [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter), an MVC framework for PHP